# Postfix Logs + Logstash + Aggregate

Tags: logstash, postfix-mta

I'm having trouble configuring Logstash properly. There are two lines in the postfix logs that I care about:

`Jun 14 09:06:22 devmailforwarder postfix/smtp[1994]: A03CA9F532: to=<person@gmail.com>, relay=server[0.0.0.0]:25, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A0B4D5C49)`

`Jun 14 09:15:04 devmailforwarder postfix/cleanup[2023]: 0E1969F533: warning: header Subject: subjectline from server[0.0.0.0]; from=<from@gmail.com> to=<to@gmail.com> proto=SMTP helo=<server>`

My grok filter patterns are:

```
POSTFIX_QUEUEID ([0-9A-F]{6,}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{15,})
POSTFIX_STATUS (?<=status=)(.*)(?= \()
POSTFIX_PROCESS (?=postfix\/)(.*?\[)(.*?)(?=: )
POSTFIX_TO (?<=to=<)(.*?)(?=>,)
POSTFIX_RELAY (?<=relay=)(.*?)(?=,)
POSTFIX_SUBJECT (?<=Subject: )(.*)(?= from )

SMTP  ^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{DATA:hostname}%{SPACE}%{POSTFIX_PROCESS:process}%{GREEDYDATA}%{POSTFIX_QUEUEID:queueid}%{GREEDYDATA}%{POSTFIX_TO:to}%{GREEDYDATA}%{POSTFIX_RELAY:relay}%{GREEDYDATA}%{POSTFIX_STATUS:status}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:response}
CLEANUP ^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{DATA:hostname}%{SPACE}%{POSTFIX_PROCESS:process}:%{SPACE}%{POSTFIX_QUEUEID:queueid}%{GREEDYDATA}%{POSTFIX_SUBJECT:subject}%{GREEDYDATA:something2}
```

(non-working) Logstash Config is:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/mail.log*"
    exclude => "*.gz"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "postfix"
  }
}
    filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"]
    match => { "message" => ["%{SMTP}", "%{SUBJECT}"] }
  }

  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    drop {}
  }

  mutate {
    add_field => { "logstashSource" => "source-server" }
  }

  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{POSTFIX_QUEUEID}"
      code => "
        map['to'] ||= event.get('to')
        map['from'] ||= event.get('from')
        map['relay'] ||= event.get('relay')
        map['status'] ||= event.get('status')
        map['response'] ||= event.get('response')
        map['from'] ||= event.get('timestamp')
        map['relay'] ||= event.get('hostname')
        map['status'] ||= event.get('process')
        map['response'] ||= event.get('queueid')
        map['subject'] ||= event.get('subject')
        "
    map_action => "create_or_update"
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout => 2
    timeout_tags => ['aggregated']
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "postfix" {
    file {
      path => "/var/log/logstash/postfix.log"
    }
  }
}
```

My goal here would be to have one elasticsearch document where each field is populated. The cleanup messages always come in the logs first. The logs are matched by a unique queue ID. I'm struggling with getting the aggregate piece working.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Config below. Also needed to update the logstash.yml to add

> pipeline.workers: 1

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"]
    match => { "message" => ["%{SMTP}", "%{SUBJECT}", "%{CONNECTION}"] }
  }

  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    drop {}
  }

  mutate {
    add_field => { "logstashSource" => "logstash-server-name" }
  }

  if ("" in [queueid]) {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "%{queueid}"
        code => "
          map['to'] ||= event.get('to')
          map['from'] ||= event.get('from')
          map['relay'] ||= event.get('relay')
          map['status'] ||= event.get('status')
          map['response'] ||= event.get('response')
          map['from'] ||= event.get('timestamp')
          map['relay'] ||= event.get('hostname')
          map['status'] ||= event.get('status')
          map['subject'] ||= event.get('subject')
          map['queueid'] ||= event.get('queueid')
          "
      timeout => 2
      timeout_tags => ['aggregated']
      map_action => 'create_or_update'
      push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
    }
  }
}

output {
  if ("aggregated" in [tags] or "" in [connection])
  {
    elasticsearch {
      index => "postfix-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      hosts => "your-es-host-here"
    }
    file {
      path => "/var/log/logstash/postfix.log"
    }
  }
}
```